# Can xbindkey simulate multiple serial keystrokes?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose I want to assign F1 to do 2 things in succession, such as:

1. Raise my browser window (using wmctrl perhaps - which is already bound to another key binding like F8)
2. Bring focus to tab 1 (which is achieved with "Ctrl 1" in my browser of choice)

Can xbindkey syntax achieve this? Something like this:

```
"F8, Control + 1"
   F1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xbindkeys maps key presses to commands. To get it to simulate key presses, you'll need to use a program like [XMacro](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xmacro).

Comment: Thanks Josh. I'll give that a try and follow up.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat It's been almost a year. Any luck? :P

Comment: Thanks for following up. I left my job where I had this set up so haven't tried it since. I'll mark it as correct. Sorry for not doing so earlier.